# Creating build definition with visual studio

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, visual-studio-2013, build-definition

I am creating a build definition in visual studio 2013. As you know, while creating build definition we can also set the assembly (in "Automated Tests" section) which contains the unit test methods to run. I am able to create the definition till this point. Now, what I want is once the test run is over, I want to call an exe that will parse the Trx file generated as a result of test run and send the run results in an email.

Can anyone have an idea about where I can set the path to the exe and pass some arguments to it while creating build definition? If this cannot be done while creating definition, what else is the other way to achieve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you ask involves multiple steps, especially if you want to pull the tool from version control (which is IMHO the best option).
See the ALM Rangers' [Team Foundation Build Customization Guide](http://vsarbuildguide.codeplex.com/) for help and guidance on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just setup an email notification when the TFS Build completes.  That should include the test run results, and a clickable link to go to the full build report.